# PHP echo in <title> not working - Why?

Tags: php

I have the following file structure:

**header.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
         <!-- Rest of my header -->
```

**anypage.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php $title= "My gorgeous page title"; ?>
<!-- Page content here -->
```

I use this to add dynamic title to pages, as well as dynamic meta-tags, for SEO reasons

### The problem is:

`<?php echo $title ?>` only works if placed **after** `<?php $title= "My gorgeous page title"; ?>`. What to do then?

Comment: Shouldn't it be <?php echo($title); ?> I think you forgot the ";"

Comment: Assignments to variables are *side-effects*. Side-effects occur as the result of *running* something. Don't expect to be able to use paint before opening the paint can.

Comment: @Throdne: The `;` is optional in that case. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php): *"you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because at the moment you are including `header.php`, `$title` does not exist yet.

> What to do then?

Include `header.php` after you set the title. The more advance your page gets, you might want to look into frameworks which provide MVC implementations.

Comment: Just figured that out lol! Thanks - I don't understand why people is downvoting my question, it's a legit question, though the answer was pretty obvious. I've searched a lot before asking, and saw countless people figuring the same thing without an answer...

Answer (score 1):

you should include header after  declare $title.. 
  anypage.php

```
<?php 
  $title = "Your page title";
  include 'header.php'; 
?>
```